# Difference between ridge regression implementation in R and SAS

Tags: r, sas, ridge-regression

I have been reading the description of ridge regression in *[Applied Linear Statistical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007310874X)*, 5th Ed chapter 11. The ridge regression is done on body fat data available [here](http://www.cst.cmich.edu/users/lee1c/spss/V16_materials/DataSets_v16/BodyFat-TxtFormat.txt).

The textbook matches the output in SAS, where the back transformed coefficients are given in the fitted model as:
$$
Y=-7.3978+0.5553X_1+0.3681X_2-0.1917X_3
$$

This is shown from SAS as:

```
proc reg data = ch7tab1a outest = temp outstb noprint;
  model y = x1-x3 / ridge = 0.02;
run;
quit;
proc print data = temp;
  where _ridge_ = 0.02 and y = -1;
  var y intercept x1 x2 x3;
run;
Obs     Y    Intercept       X1         X2         X3

 2     -1     -7.40343    0.55535    0.36814    -0.19163
 3     -1      0.00000    0.54633    0.37740    -0.13687
```

But R gives very different coefficients:

```
data <- read.table("http://www.cst.cmich.edu/users/lee1c/spss/V16_materials/DataSets_v16/BodyFat-TxtFormat.txt", 
                   sep=" ", header=FALSE)
data <- data[,c(1,3,5,7)]
colnames(data)<-c("x1","x2","x3","y")
ridge<-lm.ridge(y ~ ., data, lambda=0.02)   
ridge$coef
coef(ridge)

>   ridge$coef
       x1        x2        x3 
10.126984 -4.682273 -3.527010 
>   coef(ridge)
                   x1         x2         x3 
42.2181995  2.0683914 -0.9177207 -0.9921824 
>
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: I have used the same data set and analyzed it in SPSS. The results are similar to SAS. However if we can standardized the data as in the book, the first value at c=0 is similar in R and SPSS (running a multiple linear regression). However the results are quite different when we move further as indicated above. I too found no clue of the difference between outputs for same data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though ridge regression looks [at first like simple algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression) the devil is in the details. Apparently original variables are scaled, and parameter $\lambda$ is not the parameter you would think it is given the original description. From what I gathered reading [the reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=zWpegyjze34C&lpg=PP1&dq=Measurement%2C%20Regression%20and%20Calibration&hl=fr&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false) given in R help page of `lm.ridge` there is no one agreed way of doing ridge regression. So the difference in results can only be explained by different algorithms used by R and SAS. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can give more detailed answer.

You can see what kind of algorithm is applied in R by looking at the source of `lm.ridge`. Just type `lm.ridge` in the R prompt.

Comment: I found this link helpful for deciphering how lm.ridge is calculating the coefficients: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg81115.html  But still puzzled how different the results are from the text I referenced and SAS, given that each is supposedly back to the original scale.

Comment: @user2040, check that the same data is used by SAS and R. If it is the same, then the only conclusion is that the algorithms are different. What SAS help page is saying?

Comment: @user2040, I've replicated [SAS ridge regression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect046.htm) on R with your data. So we know for sure that the algorithms are different.

Comment: You just beat me to that! :) I was looking at the SAS help page you referenced. I compared the RMSE (in-sample data only, did not validate with a CV or bootstrap yet) and the R result was superior.So, do you think ridge regression is best suited for prediction and not interpretting the coefficients (since the results can be so different by algorithm)? I know already that regular linear model theory (CI's, contrasts etc.) are out for ridge regression (bootstrapping gets closer but still can be misleading due to bias).

Answer (score 0):

Using lm.ridge also produces a scaling vector (try head(model) to see all the output). To get the predicted values in R that you see in SAS take the coefficients and divide by the scalar vector.

Comment: I dont get that result, can you illustrate please?