# coefficients from lm.ridge in R

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, ridge-regression

I'm new to regression, and confused about how to approach.

I am using `lm.ridge()` from the `MASS` package to perform a regression on a continuous response variable and about 280 predictor (binary) variables. The predictor variables are correlated, hence using ridge regression.
The dataset has about 13000 records.

I can formulate and run the functions to generate a model, but what I ultimately want is to figure out how much each predictor is contributing towards the response.

The model output is as:

```
> summary(mod)

 #Length Class  Mode   
 #coef   281    -none- numeric
 #scales 281    -none- numeric
 #Inter    1    -none- numeric
 #lambda   1    -none- numeric
 #ym       1    -none- numeric
 #xm     281    -none- numeric
 #GCV      1    -none- numeric
 #kHKB     1    -none- numeric
 #kLW      1    -none- numeric
```

and

```
> glimpse(mod)
 #List of 9
 # $ coef  : Named num [1:281] -0.0063 -0.0063 -0.00477 -0.0063 -0.0063 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:281] "id1" "id2" "id3" .... 
 # $ scales: Named num [1:281] 0.0595 0.0595 0.0595 0.0595 0.0595 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:281] "id1" "id2" "id3" "id4" ...
 # $ Inter : int 1
 # $ lambda: num 0
 # $ ym    : num 0.105
 # $ xm    : Named num [1:281] 0.00356 0.00356 0.00356 0.00356 0.00356 ...
 #  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:281] "id1" 
 # $ GCV   : Named num Inf
 #  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "0"
 # $ kHKB  : num -1.33e-24
 # $ kLW   : num -1.33e-24
 # - attr(*, "class")= chr "ridgelm"
```

p.s. I have modified the ids from the actual output.

I would like to know how to use the coefficients to figure out the contribution of each `id` towards the response variable.

What I'm asking is not for help with the programming aspect, but the interpretation of the coefficients. I have been through some material, and found some really helpful material on [implementation details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/difference-between-ridge-regression-implementation-in-r-and-sas?rq=1) , about [centering and scaling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia) and broadly understand how to use the `coef()`, `model$coef` and `model$scales` .

However,I would appreciate help/insights about the statistics part of interpreting the coefficients.

1. Can they be used directly and thought of weights for the inputs (like in a neural net) or because of `ridge regression` do they need to be processed somehow before they can be interpreted?
2. What does it imply if the values are mostly negative? In a context that the response variable was a measure of change in a value with respect to a base value, and ranged between 0 and 10000, which was standardised.

Thank you.